# reduce threadprivate arrays into a shared one

Tags: c, openmp

I need to perform several operation on threadprivate arrays, and then sum up the content of these into a global shared array. I've tried in two ways, the first with the `atomic` directive:

```
#define N 100
int i;
#pragma omp threadprivate(i)
double local_x[N],local_y[N],local_z[N],x[N],y[N],z[N];
#pragma omp threadprivate(local_x,local_y,local_z)

int main(){

  for(i=0;i<N;i++) x[i]=y[i]=z[i]=0.;

  eval_local_xyz(); // the content of local_x,local_y,local_z is now changed

  // now we want to collect the local arrays into the global ones
  #pragma omp parallel
  {
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
      #pragma omp atomic
      x[i]+=local_x[i];
      #pragma omp atomic
      y[i]+=local_y[i];
      #pragma omp atomic
      z[i]+=local_z[i];
    }
  }
}
```

and the other with `critical`:

```
#define N 100
int i;
#pragma omp threadprivate(i)
double local_x[N],local_y[N],local_z[N],x[N],y[N],z[N];
#pragma omp threadprivate(local_x,local_y,local_z)

int main(){

  for(i=0;i<N;i++) x[i]=y[i]=z[i]=0.;

  eval_local_xyz(); // the content of local_x,local_y,local_z is now changed

  // now we want to collect the local arrays into the global ones
  #pragma omp parallel
  {
    #pragma omp critical (sumx)
    for(i=0;i<N;i++) x[i]+=local_x[i];
    #pragma omp critical (sumy)
    for(i=0;i<N;i++) y[i]+=local_y[i];
    #pragma omp critical (sumz)
    for(i=0;i<N;i++) z[i]+=local_z[i];
  }
}
```

For large N the second method seems faster than the first. However I get slightly different results from the two methods. The question is: should these two methods produce the same exact result or not?

Comment: How much they differ?

Comment: let's say that if we repeat the `eval_local_xyz()` + the parallel section iteratively 10^6 times, then the final x,y,z vectors will be visibly different with the two methods

Comment: This seams normal to me, fp summation is non-commutative. The method 2 is essentially what the `reduction` clause does automatically (for arrays available only in Fortran).

Comment: so do you think the difference is only due to round-off errors?

Comment: you're probably right, since the serial execution gives a different result as well.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25860829/why-i-am-getting-different-results-between-serial-and-openmp-pi-calculation-prog

Comment: @cipper. In the serial case try comparing with and without `-ffast-math` (or compare `-O3` to `-Ofast`).